# Get rows and count using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**UPDATE 1:**

I've just noticed `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` in the manual, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the code below in the original question and/or if this will answer my question?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I currently have the following which works, it returns rows of data:

```
function my_function()
{
    $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=server;dbname=database", "user", "pass" );
    $DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "select * from table 1" );

    $STH -> execute();

    $ROWS = $STH -> fetchAll();

    foreach($ROWS as $ROW) {
        $output .= $ROW["col1"] . " - " . $ROW["col2"] . "<br />";
    }

    $DBH = null;

    return $output;
}
```

How do I get a count of the number of rows returned?  I've looked into PDO's rowCount() function, but that returns rows effected on `update`, `insert`, or `delete`.  I would like to get a count of the number of rows return from a `select`.

I understand I can increment an integer i.e. i++ in the loop, but that seems a little primitive.  I'm guessing there is a nicer way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns the number of rows matched when used with a SELECT statement.

Comment: So if the question above gives me 10 rows from the select statement, rowCount will give me 10?

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. From the php doc: `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.` It is not used for SELECT.

Comment: *For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() **does not** return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.*

Answer (score 2):

```
count($ROWS);
```

?